# ACF Pro, three way relationship, Front end error

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-wordpress-pages, acfpro

For example let's take three post types:

A = Speaker, B = Event Name, C = Venue

A is related to B

B is related to A

but A is not related to C

but B is related to C

While creating posts in B, I choose both relationship fields. i.e. A and C

When I try to show this in front end of A, B is shown correctly, while C's post gives an error "Array" or sometimes "field_******"

Can you help me with this?

I am trying to create a page for Speaker, where I can display all the event happening for Speaker as well the Venue for the event all on one page. And I want to keep these three post types.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to display this? And the code that gives the error?